# Why my RPI in showing black screen and two icons?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, kernel, boot-issues

I'm able to boot into Raspbian, but the screen is black and is showing the icons and I'm not able to use Keyboard or mouse. It was working fine until today.

[image: screen]

and this is what I'm getting before the login. Is this a kernel error?

[image]

Comment: The good news is that it's probably not a kernel issue, and that your file system seems to recover. Can you log in to this machine by `ssh`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a kernel error?

Probably not.  It is more likely evidence of a corrupted filesystem, especially since `fsck` (which can usually repair minor problems) failed.

You'll need to either:

1. Run `fsck` on all partitions in another computer to see what it says there.
2. Restore the card from backup.
3. Recreate the card.

Comment: Thank you goldilocks! 
Could you please tell me how to restore the card from backup?

Comment: If you're asking that question, it presumably means you don't have a backup, so you can rule out #2.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it before I'm doing the "startx"? Could you give me an example please? Thank you.

Comment: If you mean create a backup, no, it's too late.  You create/keep a backup *before* you need it.  Sort of like insurance.   If you wait until your house burns down and then ask for some, they will tell you, "Sorry, you don't have a house to insure anymore."

Comment: I referring to recreate the card.

Comment: The same way you did it in the first place.  If you bought the card ready made, follow the instructions [provided by the Foundation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).

Answer (score 0):

As goldilocks said, your file system is most likely corrupt. To make a backup of your files, you could plug the sd card into a computer and copy all of the important files you would like to keep before you put a new image on the sd card.